# Path of image code in magento

Tags: magento

I am using magento 1.6.I want to know which files contains the code for image functions like when you uploading the image ,excluding the image etc.Actually i want to hide products as per user category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several files handling your images. Look at app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Image.php as an entry point.

Comment: ok i saw it. i want to implement this:i want to place a checkbox in the product images tab(when user add a new product). When a user click on check box,the changes should be reflected to the database.So for that which code i need to modify.It is like when user click on exclude button,the image is excluded from frontend.